# exporting and importing com.mongodb.BasicDBList in mongodb to csv

Tags: mongodb

How do I export and import com.mongodb.BasicDBList from mongoDB to CSV . I am able to export but when I import it is not written in the same format. The data in mongo DB is in format

#

"OrderItem" : [ { "ASIN" : "B00GN7ILVE" }, { "ASIN" : "B0006O2S1E"}, { "ASIN" : "B00FPQXPKQ" }, { "ASIN" : "B003RIUBJ2"}]

#

Changes to 
"OrderItem" : {"0":{"ASIN" : "B00GN7ILVE" },"1": { "ASIN" : "B0006O2S1E"}, "2":{ "ASIN" : "B00FPQXPKQ" }, "3":{ "ASIN" : "B003RIUBJ2"}}

In the fieldsFile as input to export I refer OrderItem as OrderItem.0 , OrderItem.1 so on.

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you've already done. Without seeing your code it's hard to give meaningful advice.

Comment: I am using mongo export/import Commands to export and import a CSV fie to mongodb
mongoexport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --db meteor --collection orders --type csv --fieldFile fields.txt --out orders.csv
mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --db meteor --collection orders --type csv --headerline --file orders.csv

Comment: If you want to import data in the same format (and using the same versions of `mongoimport` and `mongoexport`), you should not have to specify a fieldsFile. Referring to `OrderItem` as `OrderItem.0` will create a new embedded field `0` in `OrderItem` so you are requesting a different format from the original. FYI, if you want to backup & restore with type fidelity you should generally be using [binary BSON dumps](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/#binary-bson-dumps) with `mongodump`/`mongorestore`.